# View/Manage Web Apps published through Google Apps Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

Is there a way to view & manage the scripts I have deployed as a web app through the Google Apps Script Editor?

I stored a script on my google drive, opened it with Google Apps Script, and deployed via 'Publish -> Deploy as Web App'. After testing the script/webapp works correctly, I deleted the script project from my google drive and found that the web app is still functioning.

I can't find a way to view a list of, or manage the scripts after they have been published. Is there a console or dashboard that will show all my published scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may still be available in the Trash or Archives folder.  Searching for type:script will give you a list of all stand alone script files.  Also type:script is:trashed will find any in the trash folder.

Finding files with bound scripts associated (the script is embedded in the file) as well as any with specific permissions can be done by looking at your account's permissions. This will list every file that has had some sort of permission request. If a bound script does not require any permissions granted, I know of no way to finding the file. To see the files you have granted permission to, use this link: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Comment: Thanks, @Karl_S -  https://myaccount.google.com/permissions did the trick.